# C: How do I correctly access an Array element of a Struct passed by reference?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, member-access

I have this code:

```
typedef struct _structVar{
   int myArray[10];
} structVar;

structVar MyStruct;
```

Then I'm passing the struct by reference to a function:

```
myFunct(&MyStruct);
```

How I access array elements inside MyFunct?

```
void myFunct(structVar *iStruct){

   for(char i=0; i<10; i++)
      (*iStruct)->myArray[i] = i; //Fix Here
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: just `iStruct->myArray[i] = i;` will do.

Comment: `*iStruct` is the structure object itself, not a pointer to the structure. The "arrow" operator `->` only operates on pointers (it implies dereference).

Comment: And please remember that C doesn't have pass-by-reference at all, only pass-by-value. You pass the pointer by value, which in a way can be seen as *emulating* pass by reference, but it's still not proper reference passing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Emulating pass by reference is pass by reference. C++ adopted a built-in pass-by-reference, but that does not change the fact that if you pass by value a thing X that refers to a thing Y by pointing to it, you have passed a reference to Y.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either write

```
iStruct->myArray[i] = i;
```

or

```
(*iStruct).myArray[i] = i;
```

Comment: You should mention that the first way is the better (more usual) way.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I consider them as equivalent.:)

Comment: Of course they are equivalent, but (almost) nobody uses the second ways.